# code for hiding a larger binary image in a smaller rgb image using matlab

Tags: matlab

i have written a matlab code for hiding a larger black and white image in a smaller colour image by setting the the first bit of black and white image in lsb of r component , 2nd bit in lsb of g component and 3rd bit in lsb of b component of the colour image and so on. but only half the image is being recovered during decryption.how do i correct it?

```
//Encryption

% read in the cover object you want to use for embedding
file_name='ballon.png';
cover_object=imread(file_name);
cover_object=imresize(cover_object,[200 200]);
cr=cover_object(:,:,1);
cg=cover_object(:,:,2);
cb=cover_object(:,:,3);


% read the message image you want to hide in the cover image
file_name='man.png';
message=imread(file_name);
message=imresize(message,[600 600]);

% conversions needed to spread the image values on a 256 gray-scale
message=double(message);
message=round(message/256);
figure(1),imshow(message),title('message');

message=uint8(message);

% determine the size of cover image used for embedding
Mc=size(cr,1);  %Height
Nc=size(cr,2);  %Width

% determine the size of message object to embed
Mm=size(message,1);         %Height
Nm=size(message,2);         %Width


%y = uint8(wgn(Mm,Nm,1));


% set the LSB of cover_object(ii,jj) to the value of the MSB of watermark(ii,jj)
wr=cr;
wg=cg;
wb=cb;
i=1;
j=1;
for ii= 1:Mc
 for jj = 1:Nc

   wr(ii,jj)=bitset(wr(ii,jj),1,message(i,j));

   wg(ii,jj)=bitset(wg(ii,jj),1,message(i+1,j));

   wb(ii,jj)=bitset(wb(ii,jj),1,message(i+2,j));

   if j == Nm
     j=1;
     i=i+3;
   else
     j=j+1;
   end

 end

end

message_image=cat(3,wr,wg,wb);



% write to file the image
imwrite(message_image,'lsb_message.bmp','bmp');


% display encoded image
figure(2)
imshow(message_image,[])
title('encoded Image')



//Decryption



% read in encoded cover image
file_name='lsb_message.bmp';
message_image=imread(file_name);

% determine size of encoded cover image
Mw=size(message_image,1);   %Height
Nw=size(message_image,2);   %Width

enc=message_image;
er=enc(:,:,1);
eg=enc(:,:,2);
eb=enc(:,:,3);


% use lsb of encoded cover image to recover message
for ii = 1:Mw
    for jj = 1:Nw
        msg(i,j)=bitget(er(ii,jj),1);
        msg(i+1,j)=bitget(eg(ii,jj),1);
        msg(i+2,j)=bitget(eb(ii,jj),1);
        if j == Nm
         j=1;
         i=i+3;
        else
         j=j+1;
        end

    end
end




% scale the recovered message image
msg=256*double(msg);



% scale and display recovered message image
figure(1)
imshow(msg)
title('Recovered image');
```

Comment: Take a look here - http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26217-hide-images-in-image
Follows a very similar philosophy.

Comment: iam trying to hide a larger image in a smaller colour image...but the above link hides smaller image in a larger image

Comment: Yes, because both the cover and message are color images there. I would encourage you to read the comments there to get an idea if the bit setting process is the same with your case. The way the code from the link works, is that it requires the cover image to be 8 times larger (widthwise or lengthwise or mixed) than the message image.